# Retrieve subscriber status from a business unit with ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to get the business unit level subscriber status of a subscriber from a landing page within that business unit. My first thought was a retrieve request on the subscriber by subscriber key but I came to understand that only retrieves the subscriber info from the enterprise business unit.

Now I am trying to use the listsubscriber retrieverequest and get the status of the subscriber by the list ID of the all subscribers list in that business unit. While it works on lists within that business unit, it does not recognized the all subscribers list. Here is my code.

```
 Set @retrieveReq= CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
        SetObjectProperty(@retrieveReq,"ObjectType","ListSubscriber")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveReq,"Properties","SubscriberKey")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveReq,"Properties","ListID")
         AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveReq,"Properties","Status")

    Set @sf1 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
        SetObjectProperty(@sf1,"Property","SubscriberKey")
        SetObjectProperty(@sf1,"SimpleOperator","equals")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@sf1,"Value",FIELD(@row,"SUBSCRIBER KEY")) 

    SetObjectProperty(@retrieveReq,"Filter",@sf1)

    SET @srows = InvokeRetrieve(@retrieveReq, @status)
        IF RowCount(@srows) > 0 THEN
        FOR @j = 1 to RowCount(@srows) DO
          SET @srow = row(@srows,@j)
          SET @listID = FIELD(@srow, "ListID")
           IF @listID == "176" THEN 
            SET @subStatus = Concat(@subStatus,@listID,FIELD(@srow, "Status"))  
           ENDIF      
        NEXT @j
    ENDIF
```

Where 176 is the list id of my business unit. Is this some kind of permissions issue within the business unit. I have used very similar code from landing pages in a parent business unit to get listsubscribers on child business units. this is the first time I've tried from within that business unit.

Thanks
wck

Comment: Some more information: If I move my code to the parent business unit, I CAN query the all subscribers list of child business unit. Why does a landing page in a business unit not have the right to query it's own all subscriber list? How do I get around this?

Comment: I've not done this with AMP script, but you typically would need to specify the client ID when performing SOAP calls.  I am not sure if that's allowed in the AMP script or not.

Comment: +WKiraly Would you mind sharing how you resolved your issue?  I'm having the same difficulty.  

I've been attempting it via API and AMPScript and have found that all methods from the business unit landing page show the Subscriber's status on the parent level not the child business unit.

I've tried specifying the clientID on the RetrieveRequest, in a filter on Subscriber and also utilizing QueryAllAccounts --  all return the parent status.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a work around for this.

Basically if you can put your retrieve request in your parent business unit and pass the parameters using the [CloudPagesURL(ID, 'SubscriberKey', _subscriberkey, 'Email', emailaddr, 'CustomField', '')](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) to the secondary page in the child Business unit to Request the parameters from the parent BU using the [RequestParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) function - you should be able to request the subscriber status.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another workaround in SSJS.  When this is run in a Business Unit, it will only retrieve the Business Units subscriber status.

```
<script runat = "server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");


function searchAllSubscribers(){
    var searchResults = Subscriber.Retrieve()
}


var AllSubscriberResults_all = searchAllSubscribers()
var displayResults = ""

for (var i = 0; i < AllSubscriberResults_all.length; i++){
    displayResults += "Subscriber Key:" + AllSubscriberResults_all[i]["SubscriberKey"]
    displayResults += "<br />"
    displayResults += "Email Address:" + AllSubscriberResults_all[i]["EmailAddress"]
    displayResults += "<br />"
    displayResults += "Business Unit Subscription Status:" + AllSubscriberResults_all[i]["Status"]
    displayResults += "<br />"
    displayResults += "<br />"
}

</script>
<body>
    <ctrl:var name=displayResults/>
</body>
```